# How to call a function from a pointer to that function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm struggling with maybe a very simple hurdle but can't seem to understand how that works.

In my C++ project I want to provide lazy loaded classes. For this I thought of instantiating some fields of the type

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>> myClassLazyLoader;
```

At this point I'm not even sure anymore that is a valid approach, so please correct me if I'm completely off track.

I instantiate the field like this:

```cpp
myClassLazyLoader = [] { return std::make_shared<MyClass>(); }
```

To invoke the function, I tried

```cpp
myClassLazyLoader()
```

after which the compiler told me, as expected, that `std::shared_ptr<std_function<...` does not provide a call operator.

Naturally, I tried

```cpp
(*myClassLazyLoader)()
```

but then it told me that `std::function<...` also does not provide a call operator which doesn't make any sense to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, the first attempt is obviously flawed, but the second one not so, so please include the exact and full error it produces.

Comment: You have a typo in template definition, missing `()` - it should be `std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>()>`.

Answer (score 1):

The moment I posted this I figured it out. The type should be

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>()>>
```